# Is there a living R package to execute Heckman model for count data outcome?

Tags: r

Found this https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00180-017-0762-y, which no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

You can always download directly from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cran/SemiParSampleSel) with the `devtools` package:

```r
devtools::install_github("cran/SemiParSampleSel")
```

Comment: The package was removed at the request of the maintainer:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SemiParSampleSel/index.html .  You should probably contact the maintainer to find out what the issue was.